# Rust create a sink from a future

Tags: rust, async-await, future

I want to transform some reader/writer into a record pipe of elements. I managed to make the reader->stream direction using `futures::stream::unfold` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59993688/6094756). However, I'm having trouble with the sink->writer. I'm basically looking for some inverse function to `unfold`.

I know there is `AsyncWriterExt::into_sink` but this only works if I can generate all bytes to write in one batch. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141326/6094756) suggesting to use `drain()` after `with()`. This didn't work however due to lifetime issues (the `FnMut` cannot effectively store the reference to the writer, or at least I didn't manage to do this.

So what I'm looking for is some function that I could call like `fold(initial_state, |element| {(writer.write(element).await, new_state)})`. You get the idea (I hope).

I've also seen that there's `async_codec` but that seems like overkill for me. In the meantime I've resorted to storing all writes as a stream and then use `writer.into_sink().with_flat_map()`. But that's really ugly.

Comment: Please provide an example of the issue occurring in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I'm apparently not the only one wanting this, see the [upstream implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/pull/2268). Users from the future (hehe) will be able to simply use `futures::sink::unfold`.

---

Okay, I took my courage together and hacked something together based off `futures::stream::unfold`:

```rust
fn fold<T, F, Fut, Item, E>(init: T, f: F) -> FoldSink<T, F, Fut>
where
    F: FnMut(T, Item) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>
{
    FoldSink {
        f,
        state: Some(init),
        fut: None,
    }
}


use pin_project::pin_project;

#[pin_project]
struct FoldSink<T, F, Fut> {
    f: F,
    state: Option<T>,
    #[pin]
    fut: Option<Fut>,
}

impl <T, Item, F, Fut, E> futures::sink::Sink<Item> for FoldSink<T, F, Fut>
where
    F: FnMut(T, Item) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>
{
    type Error = E;

    fn poll_ready(self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), E>> {
        let mut this = self.project();

        match this.fut.as_mut().as_pin_mut() {
            Some(fut) => {
                match fut.poll(ctx) {
                    Poll::Ready(Ok(new_state)) => {
                        this.fut.set(None);
                        *this.state = Some(new_state);
                        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
                    },
                    Poll::Ready(Err(e)) => {
                        this.fut.set(None);
                        Poll::Ready(Err(e))
                    },
                    Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
                }
            },
            None => {
                Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
            }
        }
    }

    fn start_send(self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, item: Item) -> Result<(), E> {
        let mut this = self.project();
        this.fut.set(Some((this.f)(this.state.take().expect("todo invalid state"), item)));
        Ok(())
    }

    fn poll_flush(self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), E>> {
        self.poll_ready(ctx)
    }

    fn poll_close(mut self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), E>> {
        futures::ready!(self.as_mut().poll_ready(ctx))?;
        let this = self.project();
        this.state.take().unwrap();
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}
```

Comments and improvements welcome!